# Dynkin diagram construction

Tags: lie-algebras

My question is how to construct the Dynkin diagrams of a semi-simple Lie group $G$, which is the product of simple Lie groups. Is it the combinaison of Dynkin diagrams of these simple Lie groups? For example, what would the Dynkin diagram of $SU(2)\times SU(2)\times SU(2)$ look like?

Comment: it's just the disjoint union of Dynkin diagrams of the simple Lie groups. In your example it's 3 points and no edge.